# Бага анимации на jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Вообщем, [исходник](http://jsfiddle.net/killbond/nCaE8/3/). При множественной обработке события hover анимация [непонятным образом залипает](http://youtu.be/mZjYaZJUbR4). При чем залипает везде, где есть обработка hover. Кто-нибудь сталкивался? Как исправить? Вариант с задержкой обработки события не подходит (да и не решает проблемы).

Comment: @Андрей Таланин я же вам всё разжевал... и даже несколько примеров сделал. http://jsfiddle.net/nCaE8/9/ вот тут всегда будет срабатывать, у вас mouseenter заканчивается позже mouseleave, поэтому его кадры главнее. почему позже ? потому-что время анимации mouseleave меньше

Comment: по поводу "всё просто" и "нет идеи" вам не нужно обычно связывать эффект, вам нужно просто прочитать доку и сказать как по вашему это должно работать, если не работает как ожидаете - две причины: первая - вы доку не поняли (может это баг лингвистический в доке), вторая - действительно имеется проблема. Расценивайте отношение вероятностей первого ко второму случаю как 93 к 7 и все будет хорошо.

Comment: да-да, это понятно, но все же стало интересно, почему так происходит... спасибо за ответы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делайте finish();
http://jsfiddle.net/nCaE8/4/

а лучше еще и оптимизировать всё:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $ride_box = $('.ride-box'),
        value_active = $('ul li.active').position().left;
    $('ul li').hover(function () {
        $ride_box.finish();
        var value = this.offsetLeft;
        $ride_box.animate({
            left: value
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 600
        }, 'linear');
    }, function () {
        $ride_box.finish();
        $ride_box.animate({
            left: value_active
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 400
        });
    })
});
```

В документации jQuery сказано про немедленный запуск следующей анимации при `queue: false` , ничего не говорится об остановке предыдущей. Ваша анимация на mouseleave короче анимации на mouseenter, поэтому если вы заходите в блок и менее чем через 200 микросекунд его покидаете, анимация на mouseleave закончится раньше чем на mouseenter. 
рассматривайте это примерно так:

```
$('ul li').hover(
    function () {
        setTimeout(function(){console.log(1);},600);
    },
    function () {
        setTimeout(function(){console.log(2);},400);
    });
```

и ответьте себе на вопросы,

1. что будет если зайти и быстро выйти из блока ?  (в каком порядке появятся цифры 1 и 2 ?)
2. что будет если выйти не быстро ?

Comment: не спасло, бага осталась =(

Comment: Понял, в чем проблема. Все правильно, только, наверное, лучше не finish() а stop()? Вообщем это происходило из-за того что очередь анимации не использовалась - queue: false. http://jsfiddle.net/killbond/nCaE8/8/

Comment: в моем же примере проблемы  не было ? И это **перестаньте называть собственные ошибки багами библиотеки**

Comment: А как по-вашему, должен вести себя элемент посе .aminate(... , {queue: false})?

Comment: как-то так http://jsfiddle.net/8V5K6/1/ вот когда true, http://jsfiddle.net/8V5K6/2/ 

в доке же сказано про немедленный запуск следующей анимации, ничего не говорится о остановке предыдущей.

Comment: практический же смысл такого поведения можно понять сравнив эти две демки:

http://jsfiddle.net/8V5K6/3/ http://jsfiddle.net/8V5K6/4/

Comment: вот цитата:

>> A Boolean indicating whether to place the animation in the effects queue. If false, **the animation will begin immediately.** As of jQuery 1.7, the queue option can also accept a string, in which case the animation is added to the queue represented by that string.

[возможно вам поможет вот эта ссылка](http://segfault.kiev.ua/smart-questions-ru.html#itsabug)

Comment: > баг это когда поведение программного комплекса противоречит 
> описанному в документации, а не когда поведение противоречит 
> ожидаемому пользователем
Все просто - 2 события: mouseenter, mouseleave. При mouseenter блок катится в сторону элемента, на котором сработало событие, при mouseleave блок катится в исходное положение. mouseenter отрабатывается правильно, а mouseleave срабатывает не всегда. Если на другой лад, то не срабатывает при определенных условиях. У меня нет ни малейшей идеи, как этот факт связать с тем, что при этом не используется очередь анимации.